# PHP if elseif else based on array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement

My var_dump is returning this:

```
array(5) { 
    ["radioinput"]=> string(12) "sidebar-left" 
    ["option1"]=> int(0) 
    ["sometext"]=> string(0) "" 
    ["selectinput"]=> NULL 
    ["sometextarea"]=> string(0) "" 
}
```

I'm having problems acting on the "radioinput" array.

If it's "sidebar-left" I want it to echo:

`<body class="sidebar-left">`

If it's "sidebar-right" I want it to echo:

`<body class="sidebar-left">`

If it's "two-sidebars" I want it to echo:

`<body class="two-sidebars">`

If it's blank I want it to echo:

`<body class="sidebar-left">`

My questions is, how can I get my code to do this?

```
<?php 
if (radioinput('sidebar-left')) { 
    echo '<body class="sidebar-left">';
} elseif (radioinput('sidebar-right')) {
    echo '<body class="sidebar-right">';
} elseif (radioinput('two-sidebars')) {
    echo '<body class="two-sidebars">';
} else {
    echo '<body class="sidebar-left">';
}
?>
```

Comment: `$x["radioinput"]` is not an array. It is a string. It says so right there in the dump. And you didn't tell us what `$x` really is. What's wrong with basic `==` conditionals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way you are addressing your array isn't correct. I am assuming that the array is going to be called `$data`.

or replace `$data` with whatever you had on `var_dump(...)`

Then, you code would look like:

```
if ($data['radioinput'] == "sidebar-left"){
   echo '<body class="sidebar-left">';
}elseif ($data['radioinput'] == "sidebar-right"){
   echo '<body class="sidebar-right">';
}else{
   //otherwise
}
```

Edit: You can even simplify that down to:

```
if ($data['radioinput'] == "sidebar-right"){
   echo '<body class="sidebar-right">';
}else{
    echo '<body class="sidebar-left">';
}
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
if (radioinput('sidebar-left')) {
```

To this:

```
// This assumes you named the array as $array, this was not mentioned in OP
if ($array['radioinput'] == 'sidebar-left') {
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$class = $array['radioinput'] == 'sidebar-right' ? 'right' : 'left';
printf('<body class="sidebar-%s">', $class);
```